# Worst case delay for a CMOS gate

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, cmos, capacitance, delay

[image]

I want to determine the input pattern for the worst case tpHL of this CMOS gate. 
I think there may be more than one input pattern that give worst case tpHL. 
The following is my reasoning: 
The petterns: 0010>0111, 1010>0111,0000>0111 and any other pattern where the initial state has D=0 (and final state 0111 or 1011), give worst case tpHL, as in these cases the 2 internal node capacitances (in red) are charged initially and need to be discharged in addition to load capacitance (in blue).
Is this reasoning correct or is there a difference in delay between all these input patterns that I'm not accounting for?

Comment: The reasoning is correct that the foot transistor "D" is to be turned on last.  But only one pattern will give you the worst case delay. Try simulating with HSPICE!

Comment: @ammar.cma I'm trying to understand it conceptually, is there a way to determine without simulation which case would give worst case delay?